# What would define a good validation framework?

Tags: validation, frameworks

First of all, I know a lot of questions exist on this matter but, after searching through a dozen of pages, I did not find any addressing this subject from this point of view. If such a question exists, please don't hesitate to close this one.

Now, what are the specific facts that would define a good validation framework, judging by:

1. ease of use (in code, hooking into the UI)
2. ease of integration (into applications)
3. generality (platforms supported: web, desktop, etc.)
4. completeness (rules diversity)

Alternatively, what makes a validation framework bad?

Answer (score 0):

check out hibernate validator and its integration with seam(with s:validate in your inputText you can validate if data is correct)

Comment: you made mistake with community wiki, most people here answer questions only because of points.